# Django Question - Should i start a new project in the same virtual environment?

Tags: python, django

Django newbie here.

I have an existing Django virtual environment that was setup as part of a tutorial,
using Django 2.2. and Vagrant + Virtual Box on my laptop.
There was 1 project created for the tutorial above.

I will now be starting another Django tutorial,
wherein I will be creating a few more projects.

WHat is the best way to go about this?
Should I create a new virtual environment for tutorial #2?

Or use the existing environment, that was setup for tutorial #1?

FYI - tutorial #2 uses Django 1.11

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use a different virtual env for each django project.  You should keep a `requirements.txt` in the top directory of your django project.  That file tells the virtual env what packages should be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In terms of CPU resource usage, is it a big issue if I create new virtual environments for each subsequent project? I have a MBP 2014 with 16 gigs of RAM. If I am not wrong, requirements.txt applies to each individual project?

Comment: No, it won't affect performance at all. Keeping separate virtualenvs per project is just for housekeeping. Note that a Python virtual environment is not the same as virtualizing an OS - it's just a way to keep dependencies separate from other projects or from your system Python installation.

Comment: Understand. The virtualized OS  i.e. Linux virtual machine on Virtual Box is completely different from the Python virtual environment itself -> which is what we're referring to here, correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good practice to create different `virtual env` for each django project. For example if you have multiple django projects that are using one `virtualenv`, and you want to host one of the django apps on a platform like `Heroku` which will require you create a `requirements.txt` file for python apps, so when you run `pip freeze` to get the requirements, you will find out that there are many packages in that `env` that is not required by your current project. And installing all those packages on your `Heroku` might make you run out of space before you know it. So try and keep the `virtualenv` different according to your project and keep the `requirement.txt` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options for package managers:

- Pipenv
- Poetry
- Virtualenv

In general, Pipenv or Poetry are easier to use vs Virtualenv.

If you are still stuck, try using the [Imagine smart compiler](https://www.imagine.ai) that handles your package installation as well as allow you to generate the code for your application logic.

Just do

```
npx imagine create -f Django -n myapp
make install && make run
```